# ABC refuses my subclass, despite it having no abstract methods

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract-class, python-3.8

I have a `collections.abc.MutableMapping` subclass which implements the required abstract methods through monkey patching :

```py
from collections.abc import MutableMapping

def make_wrappers(cls, methods = []):
    """This is used to eliminate code repetition, this file contains around 12
    classes with similar rewirings of self.method to self.value.method
    This approach is used instead of overriding __getattr__ and __getattribute__
    because those are bypassed by magic methods like add()
    """
    for method in methods:
        def wrapper(self, *args, _method=method, **kwargs):
            return getattr(self.value, _method)(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(cls, method, wrapper)

class MySubclass(MutableMapping):
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        value = {} if value is None else value
        self.value = value

make_wrappers(
    MySubclass, 
    ['__delitem__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__setitem__']
)
```

When trying to instanciate MySubclass, I get this error :

```py
>>> c = MySubclass({'a':a, 'b':b})

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    c = MySubclass({'a':1, 'b':2})
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MySubclass with abstract methods __delitem__, __getitem__, __iter__, __len__, __setitem__
```

Yet this works :

```py
>>> MySubclass.__setitem__

<function make_wrappers.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0000020F76A24AF0>
```

**How do I force instantiation ?**

I **know** those methods work, because when I put an additional layer of inheritance between `MySubclass` and `collections.abc.MutableMapping` they magically do !

Comment: have you tried to add the methods to `cls.__dict__` instead of using `setattr`?

Comment: It appears that the [compiled code ``abc._abc_init``](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1cf15af9a6f28750f37b08c028ada31d38e818dd/Modules/_abc.c#L429) [runs when the class is created](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bef7d299eb911086ea5a7ccf7a9da337e38a8491/Lib/abc.py#L86) (i.e. evaluating the ``class`` statement) and checks whether all abstract methods are implemented. This is not re-run when adding methods after class creation. Be prepared that forcing another check after class creation might involve accessing interpreter internals.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Apparently it is checked at instanciation, not at class creation, which makes it avoidable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an `ABC` [creates a set of missing abstract methods](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1cf15af9a6f28750f37b08c028ada31d38e818dd/Modules/_abc.c#L297) [as soon as the class is created](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1cf15af9a6f28750f37b08c028ada31d38e818dd/Modules/_abc.c#L429). This must be cleared to allow instantiating the class.

```py
>>> # setup as before
>>> MySubclass.__abstractmethods__
frozenset({'__delitem__', '__getitem__', '__iter__', '__len__', '__setitem__'})
>>> MySubclass({'a':a, 'b':b})
# TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class MySubclass with abstract methods __delitem__, __getitem__, __iter__, __len__, __setitem__
>>> MySubclass.__abstractmethods__ = frozenset()  # clear cache of abstract methods
>>> MySubclass({'a':a, 'b':b})
<__main__.MySubclass at 0x1120a9340>
```

Be aware that `.__abstractmethods__` is not part of the [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) or [`abc` specification](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html). Consider it version and implementation specific – always test whether your target version/implementation uses it. It should work on CPython (testet on Py3.6 and Py3.9) and PyPy3 (testet on Py3.6), however.

---

The wrapper function can be adjusted to automatically remove monkey-patched methods from the abstract method cache. This makes the class eligible for instantiation if all methods are patched.

```py
def make_wrappers(cls, methods = []):
    """This is used to eliminate code repetition, this file contains around 12
    classes with similar rewirings of self.method to self.value.method
    This approach is used instead of overriding __getattr__ and __getattribute__
    because those are bypassed by magic methods like add()
    """
    for method in methods:
        def wrapper(self, *args, _method=method, **kwargs):
            return getattr(self.value, _method)(*args, **kwargs)
        setattr(cls, method, wrapper)
    cls.__abstractmethods__ = cls.__abstractmethods__.difference(methods)
```

Comment: Thanks ! This is perfect, I didn't know there was a cache ! I'm still a beginner despite the fact I've been coding on and off for almost a decade now x)

Comment: Just one thing tho : The **real** make_wrappers takes **two** method lists (there are two slightly different repeating patterns), how do I add the methods in both of these to the cache ? (*is there a way to do it in one line*)

Comment: @AmyLucyRose ``frozenset.difference`` takes multiple iterables, so ``cls.__abstractmethods__.difference(methods_one, methods_two)`` should work.